# how to check radio buttons with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

this is my code in html:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" id="boy" value="male" /> Boy<p></p><br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" id="girl" value="female" />Girl
<button id="fine" type="button">Submit</button>
```

and this is in my javascript file:

```
  var maskio = document.getElementById('boy');
  var femmna = document.getElementById('girl');
  function prima(){
   var fine = document.getElementById('fine');
   fine.onclick=chek;
  }
  function chek(){
  if((maskio.checked == false) && (femmna.checked == false)) {
    alert('lol');
    return false;
   }
  }
window.onload=prima;
```

Where is the problem? When i run it and click Submit nothing happens. Why?

Comment: _"...nothing happens."_ - Nothing at all? So you didn't get an error something like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null` in your browser's console? I take it your JS file is included in the document's `<head>` section?

Comment: you can fix it simply like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TQ3Xt/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JS as follows. The elements were not created by the time you were getting them.

```
function prima() {
    var fine = document.getElementById('fine');
    fine.onclick = chek;
}

function chek() {
    var maskio = document.getElementById('boy');
    var femmna = document.getElementById('girl');
    if ((maskio.checked == false) && (femmna.checked == false)) {
        alert('lol');
        return false;
    }
}

window.onload=prima;
```

Check here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/tEg2w/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your html tags, there is a space "< " remove the space and it will work fine...

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" id="boy" value="male" /> Boy
<p></p><br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" id="girl" value="female" /> Girl
<button id="fine" type="button">Submit</button>
<script>

var maskio = document.getElementById('boy');
var femmna = document.getElementById('girl');
function prima()
{
    var fine = document.getElementById('fine');
    fine.onclick=chek;
}
function chek()
{
    if(maskio.checked)
    {
        alert("You are male Eh?");
    }
    else if(femmna.checked)
    {
        alert("Femal ;)");
    }
    else if(!maskio.checked && !femmna.checked)
    {
        alert("Come on Please check something!");
    }
}
   window.onload=prima;

</script>
```

Comment: _there is a space "< "_ - What do you mean? What space? I'm fairly sure that that isn't the problem (given that there is another problem in the JS as mentioned in the other answer).

Answer (score -1):

when radio-buttons have the same name, they belong to the group of the name. That means, only one radio-button in a group can be selected. If you check both, there won't be a result, anyway !

Comment: But in this case neither is checked to start with, so that validation is to ensure that one or the other does get checked.